# What if stride size is same as input image height and width?

Tags: tensorflow

In the following code I have set stride (1,4,4,1). According to my understanding if filter size is 2*2 then above stride is not possible. but still I am getting output. Any explanation with figure is appreciated.

```
`input = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([1,4,4,2]))
filter = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([2,2,2,1]))
def conv2d(input,filter):
    return tf.nn.conv2d(input,filter,strides=[1,4,4,1],padding='SAME')
conv_out = conv2d(input,filter)
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())
print (conv_out.get_shape())`
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a fancy figure, but I guess I can help you nevertheless. Imagine your input as 2 stacked images with 4x4 pixels each. Your filter has 2 channels as well, but has only 2x2 pixels. When convoluting these now, you put the filter on the top left corner of your image and calculate the value, which consists of 8 individual products. Now, if you slide your filter with the top left pixel 4 slots to the right/down, you end up in an area right outside your image. Tensorflow recognizes this and stops calculating here. You will get the same result if you choose the valid padding, as it simply does not use padding at all.

You can check this if you use tf.ones() instead of random variables.

Answer (score 0):

The stride is the "step size" with which the filter is applied.
If you choose the stride larger than your filter size, then you simply leave input unprocessed.

The following sketch uses a 1-dimenstional input (indices are shown), filter of size 2 and stride 4:

```
0 - 1st application of kernel
1 -
2
3
4 - 2nd application of kernel after stepping 4 positions according to the chosen stride
5 -
6
7
```

"-" indicates input processed by applying the kernel.

Note that the input with indices 2, 3, 6 and 7 are not processed.